# Accessing type parameter of a parameterized type

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I have a parameterized type `A<T extends B>`, and another `C<T2 extends A>`.

Is it possible to (statically) reference `T` subclass from inside `C` without having to add `T` as a second type parameter for `C`? The objective is to add a method to `C` with return type `T`.

What I'd like to write:

```
class A<T extends B> {

}

class C<T2 extends A<T>> {
    T myMethod() {

    }
}
```

Comment: No, because generics are not part of the "interface" and erased at compile time.

Comment: @Smutje I'm talking about accessing them statically, not at runtime.

Comment: Can you give example code of what you would like to write?

Comment: Looks like someone decided to read only a part of my answer.

Comment: @Smutje please expand with a full-fledged answer

Answer (score 2):

As things stand, you've used `A` as a raw type in your definition of `C`:

```
C<T2 extends A>
```

That's a bad idea, and you can't expect to get information about the type parameters in this context because you haven't specified any. There is no `T` to find.

In your definition of `A`, the type `T` is just a parameter. Until you use a specific `A` with a particular class as a parameter, `T` doesn't refer to anything. When you define `C`, you have to say what flavour of `A` you're extending, or, in other words, specify a real type.

What you're doing is a bit like asking what the value of `x` is in `f(x) = x+1`. Until you invoke `f` with some particular argument, `x` is just a label.

Comment: why is it a bad idea? what would be a better idea? is there any different definition or class hierarchy in which I could access T?

Comment: This answer is off the mark. From any given instance of T2, there will be exactly one T for which the bound is satisfied. But Java's type inference does not try to track such functional dependencies. I think that would be impossible to implement in the presence of erasure, but I shall leave that to Smutje to explain.

Answer (score 0):

The [section 4.4 of the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) says

```
A type variable is introduced by the declaration of a type parameter of
a generic class, interface, method, or constructor.
```

The occurrence of `T` on the *right* of the `extends` is a type variable, not a type parameter. It needs to be a parameter in scope if you want to use it as a variable.

You can add `T` as a parameter like this:

```
class A<T extends B> {
    ...
}

class C<T, T2 extends A<T>> {
    T myMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

but this is what your question is trying to avoid. An alternative is to make `C` an inner class:

```
class A<T extends B> {

    class C<T2 extends A<T>> {
        T myMethod() {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is yes, you can, indirectly.

I think you can't do it directly, due to type erasure.
As others have mentioned you would have to add another parameter, or type parameter, or nested class.

You can do it indirectly using a combination of a generics function, help from the caller of the class, and help from the base class:

```
class B
{

}

class B2 extends B  // B2 is Just an example of a concrete type T 
{

}

class A<T extends B> {
  T t;
  T getT()
  {
      return t;
  }
}

class C<T2 extends A<?>> {
     T2 t2;

     T2 getT2()
     {
         return t2;
     }
     <X> X getValWithInnerType(A<? extends X> x)
     {
        return x.getT();
     }

}



public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C<A<B2>> c1 = new C<>();
        B2 inner = c1.getValWithInnerType(c1.getT2());

    }
}
```

If you are willing to get the type you want , but not necessarily directly from the C class, you can also do something simpler using composition:

```
class B
{

}

class B2 extends B
{

}

class A<T extends B> {
  T t;
  T getT()
  {
      return t;
  }
}

class C<T2 extends A<?>> {
     T2 t2;
     T2 getT2()
     {
         return t2;
     }

}



public class Example {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C<A<B2>> c1 = new C<>();
        B2 inner = c1.getT2().getT();

    }
}
```

Finally , if it's not that crucial to get the exact deriving type T, you can just have a function returning type B:

```
class B
{

}

class B2 extends B
{

}

class A<T extends B> {
  T t;
  T getT()
  {
      return t;
  }
}

class C<T2 extends A<? extends B>> {
     T2 t2;

     B getT2()
     {
         return t2.getT();
     }


}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem very useful. Can you return something other than what is in a field of a field of C? In general `myMethod` may be more complex than that. Could you write a method that has a parameter of type T?

Comment: Of course, you could write something like <T> T getValWithInnerType(T x)  {  return x;  }, but I don't think that would be useful, since you wouldn't be able to use that T in class C outside of that function.